# TypeScript object lazy init with dynamic keys

Tags: typescript

I wasn't sure how to word the question correctly, so...

I'm setting object properties lazily, but TypeScript is complaining...

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

[image]

How do I make this work?

Also, here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-maxwell-wqpl6?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: This might help https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: That's a long page to read... Did you mean to look at Optional Chaining. If so, doesn't it apply only to reading values as opposed to setting them? As you see in my example, TypeScript starts complaining when I'm trying to set a value for a key on a supposedly undefined object. Optional Chaining on the left-hand side of the equation is not allowed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your value is `optional` so it prompt error warning you value may be undefined and it may not be able to retrieve the next property `[key]`

However, you already handled it in the code when `value` is undefined, you assigned a empty object `{}` to it:

```
data[key1].values = data[key1].values || {};
```

So we can use `!` to tell typescript `values` will not be undefined anyway.

```
data[key1].values![key2] = data[key1].values![key2] || value;
return data[key1].values![key2];
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-fire-28vdy?file=/src/App.tsx:414-512)

---

More on [non null assertion `!` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)